# Magic Square Function Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, magic-square

For a project i am supposed to write my own function that will do the same thing as the magic function in matlab. I am obviously not asking anyone to write out my problem but if somebody could give me any ideas of how i could start it or example code it would be much appreciated! I am completely lost on how to start this one...

Comment: You can check out how Matlab does it by typing `edit magic` in the command prompt. That should at least give you an idea of where to start.

Answer (score 1):

This is often great advice:

> If a problem is too hard, try solving an easier one to begin with.

Try to write code to generate a 2 by 2 magic square?  Then try 3 by 3.  Then 4 by 4.  Can you see how to generalise?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already thought about it, but the usual good source of information is wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square#Types_and_construction

It explains different ways of making magic squares.

Comment: Thank you! i will try to do a little more research to see if i can come up with a more specific problem!